# Deploying a war file as a single batch file

Tags: servlets

i have developed my java web application that i need to deploy on my local server. Is there any possible way that i can have a script which will assist me execute tomcat, war file and MySQL as a single file while configuring the server and environmental variables? If you know please let me know all the necessities required and the procedures involved.

Comment: Maybe a Virtual Machine?

Comment: How, Please explain so as i get a fully understanding of all this. I will greatly appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily write such a script using Bash or Tcsh.  The **general** layout (for a Debian based machine) would be:

```
## fetch Tomcat binary
wget http://URL_TO_TOMCAT
## extract tomact
tar zxf tomcat.tgz
## deploy war file
cp YOUR_WAR.war TOMCAT_WEBAPPS_FOLDER
## install mysql
sudo apt-get install mysql
## configure the database
mysql < db_config.sql
## run tomcat 
TOMCAT_DIR/bin/startup.sh
```

Of course, this was just to give you a general idea of how to do it with shell scripts.  You can also configure your script in a way that it accepts parameters on the command line to ease the setup. See [Command Line Options: How To Parse In Bash Using “getopt”](http://www.bahmanm.com/blogs/command-line-options-how-to-parse-in-bash-using-getopt) to find out how to do it.

Also there is [Vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com/) for setting up development machines.  Haven't used it myself so you have to explore it.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Given that this is the first time am doing it, i really dont understand what all this means. Please is it possible to have your an answer for a window based machine?

Comment: I don't have enough experience with Windows scripting to be able to help you.  However, I don't think the same idea is easily applicable to a Windows machine as most of these utilities (like bash, wget, tar, cp) are not available there.  I'd say give virtual machines a try.